# Burning ship fractal

Tags: c++, fractals

I am working on a school project to generate a few escape-time fractals, in c++.
The Mandelbrot and the Julia are working normally.
For the burning ship fractal, this is the code :

```
double x0, y0;//initial co-ordinates before iterations
x0=cx; y0=cy; //being passes on values from another fn, initially -2 and -2

for(int i= 30; i<=630; i++,x0+=(double)1/m, y0=cy)//m is for the magnification
{
    for(int j= 630 ; j>=30; j--,y0+=(double)1/m)
    {
        double x= 0.0, y= 0.0, t;
        int k= -1;

        while(( x*x + y*y <4)&& k<it-1)
        {
            t= x*x - y*y + x0;
            y= 2*abs(x*y) + y0;
            x=t;
            k++;
        }
        p= k*pd;
        setcolor(COLOR(colour[p][0],colour[p][1],colour[p][2]));
        putpixel(i,j,getcolor());
    }
}
```

, which is the same as the code for the Mandelbrot set, except, instead of

```
y=2*x*y + y0;
```

for the Mandelbrot set, you use

```
y=2*abs(x*y) + y0;
```

for the Burning ship fractal, according to what I'd read up on.
But the output is totally different.

Could someone point out of there are any errors in the code or any extra things that I might need to know?

( Here's a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIr8R.png) to the image generated, with 100 iterations, on every point from a rectangle extending from (-2, 2) to (2, 2).)

And here's the code without using  , using the screen as O/P.

```
double x0, y0, t;
x0=-2,y0=-2;
for(double cx=x0; cx<=2; cx=cx+0.1, cy=-2)//cx, cy: just loop counters. 
{
    for(double cy=y0; cy<=2; cy=cy+0.1)
    {
        double x= 0.0, y= 0.0;
        int k= -1;

        while(( x*x + y*y <4)&& k<9)//k- no. of times it takes to escape out
        {
            t= x*x - y*y + cx;
            y= 2*abs(x*y) + cy;
            x=t;
            k++;
        }
        cout<<k; //for output
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

which is the same thing as the previous code sample, except there are fixed values for total iterations (10), the precision (0.1).
The O/P is:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000023999999999310000000000000
0000000000002229999999999911100000000000
0000000000222229999999999911111000000000
0000000022222299999999999991111100000000
0000000322222249999999999931111111000000
0000003352222249999999999932111111100000
0000023334222599999999999993111111110000
0000114835424499999999999993311111110000
0000112433444499999999999993331111111000
0001111473948699999999999995532111111100
0001111999596999999999999999592211111100
0011111299759999999999999999942211111110
0011111119959999999999999999842211111110
0111111119999999999999999999942211111111
0111111119999999999999999999942211111111
0111111119999999999999999999942211111111
0111111119999999999999999999992211111111
0111111149999999999999999999992211111111
0111111199999999999999999999992221111111
0111111199999999999999999999992221111111
0111111199999999999999999999999221111111
0111111999999999999999999999999222111111
0111111999999999999999999999999922111111
0111114999999999997666799999999922211111
0111114999999999654444456999999992211111
0112149999999995433333334599999994221111
0012229999999943333222333349999995211110
0022299999999432222222222234999991111110
0002299999993222222222222222399911111100
0002699999932222222212222222221111111100
0000899943222211111111111112221111111000
0000094222211111111111111111111111110000
0000022222111111111111111111111111110000
0000002211111111111111111111111111100000
0000000111111111111111111111111111000000
0000000001111111111111111111111100000000
0000000000111111111111111111111000000000
0000000000001111111111111111100000000000
0000000000000011111111111110000000000000
```

Comment: `x0` and `y0` are not initialized to `0`, yet you increment them. Then you have a local `t` that overrides the `t` in a higher scope (which is also uninitialized). Edit: Also `m` is not specified. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @AndyG : thanks for pointing that out, that was bad coding. I hadn't included the initialization of `x0`and `y0` in the code sample, thinking it was unrelated. Also, I removed the local `t`[which wasn't actually making a difference, but yes, it is better removed]. I've checked the o/p, it's the same.

Comment: @AndyG : No, it did not, the O/P is the same.

Comment: Following the edit in my original comment, perhaps you could provide a [mcve] where the ouput is actually a short list of numbers that we can hand-check against the right answer.

Comment: Also, check the prototype of `abs()`, in some compilers it returns `int`, in this case you need `fabs()` instead.

Comment: @SergeiKulik  Yes, that was the solution, thanks. I got the correct output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mandelbrot Set Fractal Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815668/mandelbrot-set-fractal-code)